# Swift: How to change text in Cell.TextLabel alignment to get displayed from Right to Left?

Tags: ios, swift, cell, uitableview

I have a table that displays some data, but the text label is aligned from left to right by default, what I need is to change it to be from right to left.

I tried to call `textAlignment`

```
cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Right;
```

but, it didn't work, so I tried to change the width of the `textLabel` as I thought It was the problem:

```
cell.textLabel?.frame.size.width = 320
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Right;
```

but it didn't work as well.

NOTE: I created my cell programmatically, not using drag and drop in the storyboard.

I need the text labels to be in the red rectangle [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW167.png)

Comment: you mean that if you assign "hello world" to the label's text property it should display "dlrow olleh"?

Comment: that would be funny!!! :P Could you pls provide an example text ? @NABS

Comment: No, I mean I'm developing an Arabic App, the Arabic language gets written from right to left as the opposite of the other languages. I will provide a capture to support my question

Comment: so if you enter hello world.... it should be displayed as world hello from left to tight ?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: No, I just need to change the alignment of the textLabel I want it to be from Right to left instead of from left to right

Comment: check my answer @NABS

Answer (score 1):

iOS supports rightToLeft by itself just add the language. Select your project -> Info -> Localizations -> +

[image]

Comment: I added Arabic but still, the cells' text labels are located on the left

Answer (score 1):

```
 cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

On `.Center` you can add `.Right` or `.Left` depending where you want the text to be

Answer (score 0):

if your app supports the arabic language (you have to add arabic language to your project in the project settings) it will handle the rest for you.

after you added the language you can even see a preview in the assistant editor.

Comment: I didn't find an option of adding new language in project setting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight
```